# Help with finding basis of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let 
$A =
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
2 & -3 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
1 & -3 & 2 \\
\end{array}\right]$

and vector 
$u = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
2 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{array}\right]$

- Find basis for vector space that is generated by vectors: $u, Au, A^2u, ... , A^{121}u$
- Find basis of vector space $R(A^{78})$ (row space of matrix)

I know how to find basis for a vector space but I don't know how to solve this particular exercise (mainly those powers of $A$).

Comment: Notice that Au=u.

Comment: And also that $A^2=A$.

Comment: I totally missed that! So I am basically finding basis for space that is generated by $u, Au$? Since every other power of $A$ is again $A$ and also $Au = u$?

Answer (score 0):

let $v^T = \pmatrix{2&-3&1}, w^T = \pmatrix{1&-1&0}, x^T = \pmatrix{1&0&-1}$ are the left  eigenvectors of $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalues $0, 1, 1$ respectively. that is $v^TA = 0, w^TA = w, x^T A = x$ and also $\{v, w, x\}$ form a basis of $R^3.$ therefore a basis for the row sapce of $A^{78}$ is $\{w, x  \}.$